# Hammer.js for Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, hammer.js

I use hammer.js in my applications (Angular 2 and 5). 
I use events from this library, as example - tap.
If I destroy any DOM-element with the help of *ngIf, there's subscription on the event. As a result, there's a reference to the DOM-object in the memory.

[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/He3CLtZMV0C5v1n6zF7i?p=preview)

```
<div class="nnn"
     (tap)="ontp()"
></div>

<ng-container *ngIf="_show">
    <div class="arr"
         *ngFor="let item of _items"
         (tap)="onT()"
    > 
        {{item}} 
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

How I can remove listener from this DOM-element?

[without tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peiAR.png)
[with tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsKsn.png)

Comment: Shouldn't Angular take care of that automatically? Otherwise, thousands and thousands of listeners would be added after the view gets redrawn many times. My guess is that all listeners are removed before redraw and recreated

Comment: *As a result, there's a reference to the DOM-object in the memory*, and that's memory leak. If you're totally sure that it isn't removed on GC, consider opening an issue in Angular repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in Angular:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22155
Pull request and workaround:
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/22156